# Transloadit upload video and pdf files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file-upload, transloadit

I have a two video and a pdf file that i'm trying to upload via my form. Following is my assembly:

```
$(document).ready ->
  $("#new_coach").transloadit
    wait: true
    triggerUploadOnFileSelection: false
    params:
      auth:
        key: "xxxxxxxxxxxx"

      steps:
        encode:
          use: ":original"
          robot: "/video/encode"
          preset: "iphone"
          width: 320
          height: 240

        export:
          robot: "/s3/store"
          key: "<%= Settings.aws.key %>"
          secret: "<%= Settings.aws.secret %>"
          bucket: "<%= Settings.aws.bucket %>"

  return
```

I checked my assembly on the site in my account and uploaded files are 3 but results shows only 2 files under encoded section and the pdf is gone. How do I save the pdf file??

Answer (score 0):

If you don't specify the `use` parameter, the `export` step will only use the results from the previous step. A solution would be to set

```
use: [ ":original", "encode" ]
```

In your `export` step.